# Is there any way to remove the Search Box from the SharePoint Online team site?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

[image: Search Page]

I need to remove the *Search Site Pages* section from my SharePoint team site.
The main purpose of doing so is that: When I open the site on my mobile phone, because of this Search Box, the keyboard automatically opens as soon as the page launches. It becomes very troublesome and non-user friendly to browse the page. So I need to remove that Search Box panel completely.
Is there any way out???

Answer (score 0):

No OOB settings for this, you need develop SPFx application customizer to do it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/build-a-hello-world-extension

```
const css: string = 'div.od-Search{display:none !important}';
      if (css) {
          // inject the style sheet
          const head: any = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement;
          let customStyle: HTMLStyleElement = document.createElement("style");
          head.appendChild(customStyle);
          customStyle.title = "MSCustom";
          customStyle.type = "text/css";
          customStyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css))
      }
      return Promise.resolve<void>();
```